# Why Web Audio API isn't supported in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, web-audio-api

I understand *Web Audio API* is a client side feature but nodejs is based on V8 Chrome client side implementation of ECMAScript, which include *Web Audio API*.
Why there is no complete support of *Web Audio API* in nodejs ?
Is it because *AudioContext* is based on the global *window* object ?
Am I missing a point here ?
Is there a plan to make it available in the future ?

Comment: The Web Audio API is like the DOM or requestAnimationFrame - it's a web platform feature, not part of the JavaScript language.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-audio-api and https://www.npmjs.com/browse/keyword/webaudio.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Node.js doesn't support Web Audio because it isn't part of the [JavaScript language](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html) itself - it's a separate [web platform JavaScript API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API).

You can think of it like Web Workers, `requestAnimationFrame` or `XMLHttpRequest` - they are part of the browser's JavaScript environment, but they don't necessarily make sense for other runtimes.

V8 is a generic JavaScript engine; it doesn't include web platform features. That's one of the reasons that Node.js is able to use it. [Chrome's implementation of Web Audio](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/modules/webaudio/AudioContext.cpp&sq=package:chromium&type=cs) is part of Blink, the rendering engine.

The [web-audio-api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-audio-api) npm module aims to implement Web Audio for Node.js.

Comment: This is more clear for me now, thank you for explanations. I'll take a look at _Blink_ project.

Answer (score 3):

The reason why the Web Audio API (WAA) is not implemented in NodeJS is fundamentally a design decision. And the fact that `AudioContext` is part of `window` has nothing to do with it. For example, `console` is part of `window` interface but is in "node-core".

The fact that the WAA is not part of ECMAScript specs is also not sufficient to explain why WAA is not in node-core. For example HTTP2, web crypto API, setInterval(),... are not in ECMAScript spec but are in node-core.

There is no clear cut between what should be in node-core, and what should be in userland (meaning not be in node-core). But in general, NodeJS prefers to keep its standard lib small, expirements new API in userland. You can read this article which talks about that in more depth [(see)](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-node-core-verus-userland/).

Should we see WAA in node-core in near future? Probably not [(see issue #64546)](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/34546), but it doesn't mean that 's impossible.

I should add that portability in Audio programming is not an easy task, and this certainly explain in part why NodeJS maintainers are not eager to implement WAA in core.